# Passing Data from ChildViewController to ParentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 views, `ParentViewController` and `ChildViewController`; I want to nest `ChildViewController` inside `ParentViewController`. I have designed `ParentViewController` and `ChildViewController` in Storyboard. `ParentViewController.m` contains the logic for the parent and `ChildViewController.m` contains the logic for the child. In `ParentViewController.m` I add the child like so:

```
 ChildViewController *childVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildSBI"];
 [self addChildViewController:childVC];
```

My Question: How can I receive information (like an NSString) from the child back to the parent? Should I do this through `delegation`?

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern would be to have the `child` as a property of the `parent`, and have the `parent` be a delegate of the `child`. The first thing you need to do is make your own protocol.

```
// MyProtocol.h
- (void)heyParentSomethingHappened:(Something)something;
```

Next, make the `child` a property of the `parent` so they can talk through delegation.

```
// ParentVC.m
@interface ParentVC()
@property (nonatomic) ChildVC *child
@end
```

Now that the `parent` has the `child` as a property, they need some way to talk. This is where the delegation comes in. Have the parent conform to `MyProtocol`.

```
// ParentVC.h
@interface ParentVC : UIViewController <MyProtocol>
```

Now that the `parent` conforms to your special protocol, have the `child` make it a delegate.

```
//ChildVC.h 
@interface ChildVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) id <MyProtocol> delegate.
@end
```

Now that the `child` has the `delegate` property, set it to the parent and you are good to go.

```
// ParentVC.m
- (id)init {
    // do your init
    self.child.delegate = self // both (child.delegate, self) conform to <MyProtocol>, so no type mismatch.
}
```

Now when your `child` needs to alert your `parent` of something, they have a formal way of talking through the protocol + delegation.

```
// ChildVC.m
- (void)someFunc {
    [self.delegate heyParentSomethingHappend:[Something new]];
}
```

Remember to always include the protocol file when using it.

Comment: thanks. How would I do this with blocks?

Comment: Just change your protocol to include methods that allow blocks to be passed. @Apollo